# How do I find the nth DayOfWeek for a given month?

Tags: c#

I am trying to find the nth DayOfWeek for a given month (in a given year).

For example: I am looking for the 3rd Saturday of May (2019).

I failed to come up with a working solution using the `DayOfWeek` extension method. Do I have to loop through the entire month to find the third Saturday?

Comment: You could loop until you find the first Saturday and then add 2 weeks.

Comment: Great idea @David! Thank you!!!

Comment: You know how many days have to be added (as you know the current day), so a loop is a bit strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could of course loop through the entire month but I think this is a more elegant way (taken from [here](https://www.codenewengland.com/2009/04/11/find-the-next-nth-dayofweek-for-a-given-month/)):

```
private static DateTime FindTheNthDayOfWeek(int year, int month, int nthOccurrence, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
    {
        if (month < 1 || month > 12)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Invalid month");
        }

        if (nthOccurrence < 0 || nthOccurrence > 5)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Invalid nth occurrence");
        }

        var dt = new DateTime(year, month, 1);

        while (dt.DayOfWeek != dayOfWeek)
        {
            dt = dt.AddDays(1);
        }

        dt = dt.AddDays((nthOccurrence - 1) * 7);

        if (dt.Month != month)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(string.Format("The given month has less than {0} {1}s", nthOccurrence, dayOfWeek));
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

This private method doesn't loop through the entire month but stops already once the first DayOfWeek has been found. Then you simply add a week for each nth occurrence (minus the already added week ;-) ).

Answer (score 1):

If you talk about dates it should be related to some calendar, in my example Gregorian.

```
public static class DataTimeExt
{
    public static IEnumerable<DateTime> TakeWhileInclusive(this DateTime value,
        Func<DateTime, bool> func)
    {
        DateTime dt = value;

        yield return dt; //[first            
        while (func(dt = dt.AddDays(1))) yield return dt; //in between            
        yield return dt; //last]
    }
}
```

then you could just iterate through the dates until Sunday and then add 14 days.

```
var calendar = new GregorianCalendar();

var dates = new DateTime(2019, 5, 1, calendar)
    .TakeWhileInclusive(dt => calendar.GetDayOfWeek(dt) != DayOfWeek.Sunday);

Console.WriteLine(dates.Last().AddDays(14));
```

Answer (score 1):

I created two extension methods, where one gets the next DayOfWeek from the date, optionally including the date itself, and the other for the previous DayOfWeek, with the same functionality.

```
public static DateTime Next(
  this      DateTime source,
  DayOfWeek dayOfWeek,
  bool      considerSameDate
) => ( dayOfWeek - source.DayOfWeek) is var difference
  && difference < (considerSameDate ? 0 : 1)
  ? source.AddDays(difference + 7)
  : source.AddDays(difference)
  ;
```

and

```
public static DateTime Previous(
  this DateTime source,
  DayOfWeek     dayOfWeek,
  bool          considerSameDate
) => dayOfWeek == source.DayOfWeek
     ? ( considerSameDate ? source : source.AddDays(-7) )
     : source.AddDays(
         ( dayOfWeek - source.DayOfWeek ) is var difference
         && difference > 0
         ? difference - 7
         : difference
     );
```

Having these, one can ask the questions you posed:

```
var x = new System.DateTime(2019, 5, 1).Next(System.DayOfWeek.Saturday, true).AddDays(14);
```

I create a new DateTime (2019-05-01), call Next with Saturday and consider 5/1 as a candidate, and then add 14 days, which makes it to the third Saturday of May, 2019.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple and clean with no looping. Just a little arithmetic.

```
static DateTime? NthWeekDayOfMonth( int n, DayOfWeek dow, int year , int month)
{
  DateTime startOfMonth      = new DateTime( year, month, 1 ) ;
  int      offset            = ( 7 + dow - startOfMonth.DayOfWeek ) % 7 ;
  DateTime nthWeekDayOfMonth = startOfMonth
                             .AddDays( offset    )
                             .AddDays( 7 * (n-1) )
                             ;
  bool isSameMonth           =  startOfMonth.Year  == nthWeekDayOfMonth.Year
                             && startOfMonth.Month == nthWeekDayOfMonth.Month
                             ;
  return isSameMonth
    ? nthWeekDayOfMonth
    : (DateTime?) null
    ;
}
```